# How to define "UCHAR * POINTER_32" and "VOID * POINTER_32" types in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

### Background:

Translating the [`IP_OPTION_INFORMATION32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structures for 64-bit compiler I got stucked with data types to use there. Structure definitions from the reference:

**The IP_OPTION_INFORMATION32 structure:**

```c
typedef struct _IP_OPTION_INFORMATION32 {
  UCHAR              Ttl;
  UCHAR              Tos;
  UCHAR              Flags;
  UCHAR              OptionsSize;
  UCHAR * POINTER_32 OptionsData;
} IP_OPTION_INFORMATION32, *PIP_OPTION_INFORMATION32;
```

I would translate this way (for Delphi XE2, 64-bit target platform). As you can see, I don't know what type to use for the `OptionsData` field of the structure:

```pascal
IP_OPTION_INFORMATION32 = record
  Ttl: UCHAR;
  Tos: UCHAR;
  Flags: UCHAR;
  OptionsSize: UCHAR;
  OptionsData:       // what should I use here for UCHAR * POINTER_32 ?
end;
```

**ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32 structure:**

```c
typedef struct icmp_echo_reply32 {
  IPAddr                         Address;
  ULONG                          Status;
  ULONG                          RoundTripTime;
  USHORT                         DataSize;
  USHORT                         Reserved;
  VOID * POINTER_32              Data;
  struct ip_option_information32  Options;
} ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32, *PICMP_ECHO_REPLY32;
```

For Delphi XE2 64-bit target platform I would write:

```pascal
ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32 = record
  Address: TIPAddr;  // defined before
  Status: ULONG;
  RoundTripTime: ULONG;
  DataSize: USHORT;
  Reserved: USHORT;
  Data:              // what should I use here for VOID * POINTER_32 ?
  Options: IP_OPTION_INFORMATION32;
end;
```

### Question:

How would you define the `UCHAR * POINTER_32` and `VOID * POINTER_32` types in Delphi for 64-bit platform target ? As far as I know, there is no 32-bit pointer type available for 64-bit platform target and I just don't like it to be defined e.g. as a `Int32` type :-)

What is the most precise translation for the mentioned types ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue of what `POINTER_32` is covered in another Stack Overflow question: [POINTER_32 - what is it, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447812/pointer-32-what-is-it-and-why)

You would use it when performing interop with structs that are defined in a different process, one that has 32 bit pointers.

You don't have the equivalent of `__ptr32` in Delphi so you have simply no choice other than to declare it as a 32 bit integer. I would use an unsigned type.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to use `Cardinal` for that field, but either I've translated the structures wrong or MS have incorrect documentation for them. My testing [`project is here`](https://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2F17084031) if someone would like to play with. For 64-bit platform target the function call succeeded [`only if I used`](https://code.google.com/p/projects-stackoverflow-tlama/source/browse/trunk/17084031/PingUnit.pas#32) `Pointer` for the `POINTER_32` data type. Quite strange...

Comment: And yes, I have tried even to send some data as a request (the `RequestData` parameter), but it's the same. The `IcmpSendEcho` function call just fails with the error 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`) unless I defined the `POINTER_32` data type as `Pointer`, which is against original `POINTER_32` definition.

Comment: @TLama I don't know what the problem is with your program, but my answer is clearly accurate as demonstrated by this simple program: http://pastebin.com/e7hGhtuf

Comment: The problem was that I was assuming that field to be a 32-bit pointer, but it's actually a pointer to a 32-bit pointer, isn't it ? So although your post is correct, the answer to my question (how to define `UCHAR * POINTER_32` and `VOID * POINTER_32` types in Delphi for 64-bit platform target) is actually just a `Pointer` or am I wrong ?

Comment: No, when you target 64 bit, the `POINTER_32` macro evaluates to `__ptr32`. And `UCHAR * __ptr32` is a 32 bit pointer to `UCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `UInt32` (or Cardinal, DWORD etc - anything unsigned 32 bit) would be fine. All you need to do is to declare unsigned 32 bit at proper position of structure (record). CPU would not care, compiler would not care (you can typecast to pointer if needed) is it actually a pointer or not. Even signed 32 bit would work unless you would do some math with value and processor's flags checking.
And another thing in structure translations from C to Delphi: be sure that original alignment was 4 bytes (32 bit per item), because `record` unlike `packed record` (no alignment) by default using same 4 bytes alignment. Else you can have issues by applying your records to data like

```
type
  Picmp_echo_reply32 = ^icmp_echo_reply32;
...
  data_size := Picmp_echo_reply32(@mybuf[some_offset]).DataSize;
```

or

```
var
  icmp_echo: Picmp_echo_reply32;
...
  icmp_echo := @buf[offset];
  reserved := icmp_echo.Reserved;
```

Comment: Default alignment for Delphi matches default alignment for Windows header files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question when tried to make work an old code with IcmpSendEcho() on 64-bit target platform.

In my case, i left type "Pointer" for struct fields "Options" and "OptionsData". And it worked fine.

If I used any other type - then field "Options" filled incorrectly on 64-bit platform.
So compiler correctly defined all alignments for case of Pointer type.

But I had some another problems.

In my legacy code structs were "packed" and I had to remove "packed" keyword.

And, the second problem - IcmpSendEcho() had failed until I set additional bytes for ReplySize (although MSDN says it is 8 bytes of data, but on 64-bit platform it returned no error only when ReplySize holded additional 16 bytes instead of 8). But I set it to 16 additional bytes and all is ok.

My code:

```
type
  ip_option_information = record
    Ttl: Byte;
    Tos: Byte;
    Flags: Byte;
    OptionsSize: Byte;
    OptionsData: Pointer;
  end;

  icmp_echo_reply = record
    Address: TInAddr;
    Status: Cardinal;
    RTTime: Cardinal;
    DataSize: Word;
    Reserved: Word;
    Data: Pointer;
    Options: ip_option_information;
  end;

...

  TIcmpSendEcho = function(
    IcmpHandle: THandle;
    DestAddress: TInAddr;
    RequestData: PVOID;
    RequestSize: Word;
    RequestOptns: PIPINFO;
    ReplyBuffer: PVOID;
    ReplySize: DWORD;
    Timeout: DWORD
  ): DWORD; stdcall;

...

var
  hIP: THandle;
  pingBuffer: array [0 .. 31] of AnsiChar;
  pIpe: ^icmp_echo_reply;
  lwsaData: WSAData;
  DestAddress: In_Addr;
  wVersionRequested: Word;
  LSize: Integer;

...

  pingBuffer := 'String of 32 chars for ping test';

{$IFDEF WIN64}
  LSize := SizeOf(icmp_echo_reply) + SizeOf(pingBuffer) + 16;
{$ELSE}
  LSize := SizeOf(icmp_echo_reply) + SizeOf(pingBuffer) + 8;
{$ENDIF}

  GetMem(pIpe, LSize);
  try
    ZeroMemory(pIpe, LSize);

    wVersionRequested := MakeWord(1, 1);
    if WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, lwsaData) <> 0 then
      Exit;

    try
      hIP := IcmpCreateFile();
      try
        if (IcmpSendEcho(hIP, DestAddress, @pingBuffer, sizeof(pingBuffer), nil, pIpe, LSize, 5000) = 0)
            or (pIpe.Status <> IP_SUCCESS) then
          Exit;

        LMessage := 'Answer from ' + IpToString(pIpe^.Address) + ' ' +
                        'Answer time: ' + IntToStr(pIpe.RTTime) + ' ms';
      finally
        IcmpCloseHandle(hIP);
      end;
    finally
      WSACleanup();
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(pIpe);
  end;
```