# What's the point of __ptr32 and __ptr64?

Tags: pointers, visual-c++

As described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985900%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), Microsoft has these two type annotations to declare native pointers on different architectures. However, on the second line:

> On a 32-bit system, a pointer declared with __ptr64 is truncated to a 32-bit pointer. On a 64-bit system, a pointer declared with __ptr32 is coerced to a 64-bit pointer.

This sounds to me like the declaration doesn't matter; if the architecture overrides the declaration of __ptrXX to be the default anyways, what's the point of marking __ptrXX in the first place?

I see that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3449361/1092672) says that it's for interop, but if the declarations are essentially overridden as above, how does that help with interop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a big difference between declaring and assigning a 32-bit pointer and actually using it.  In other words, dereferencing the pointer.  If you do that in a 64-bit process then there is no other option but to sign-extend it to a 64-bit pointer.  Which is what "coerced" means.  That *may* work by accident, but you'd have to be pretty lucky.  It just doesn't make sense to try.

The point of declaring a __ptr32 is as described in that linked answer, it only makes sense when you interop with a 32-bit process.  Which uses 32-bit pointers.  It is not common.

Comment: That the coercion doesn't happen immediately and is actually avoided, makes this clear. I'm curious and know little about interop: do 32-bit programs every practically interop with 64-bit programs? I.e. does the reverse ever happen, or is the __ptr64 just there for symmetry/having the theoretical possibility?

Comment: According to [this](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2013/05/msvc-pointer-type-attributes/), a `__ptr32` is always 32 bits, and a `__ptr64` is always 64 bits, regardless of the target platform.  32-bit programs only use the low 32 bits of a `__ptr64`, dynamically truncating the 64-bit value into a 32-bit value.  Weirdly, however, the compiler doesn't consider `T* __ptr32` and `T* __ptr64` distinct types, although it does recognise the size difference.