# WinAPI IcmpSendEcho on 64-bit platform

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-10-desktop, win64

I am trying to send a ping request with the `IcmpSendEcho` function provided by Windows, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho).
For the most part, it seems straightforward, however, I am having trouble understanding how the caller-provided echo request buffer (`LPVOID ReplyBuffer` and `DWORD ReplySize` parameters) should be set up and used. The documentation states the following:

> `ReplyBuffer`
>   [...]
>   A buffer to hold any replies to the echo request. Upon return, the buffer contains an array of ICMP_ECHO_REPLY structures followed by the options and data for the replies. The buffer should be large enough to hold at least one ICMP_ECHO_REPLY structure plus RequestSize bytes of data.
>   On a 64-bit platform, upon return the buffer contains an array of ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32 structures followed by the options and data for the replies.

and

> `ReplySize`
>   [...]
>   The allocated size, in bytes, of the reply buffer. The buffer should be large enough to hold at least one ICMP_ECHO_REPLY structure plus RequestSize bytes of data. On a 64-bit platform, The buffer should be large enough to hold at least one ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32 structure plus RequestSize bytes of data.
>   This buffer should also be large enough to also hold 8 more bytes of data (the size of an ICMP error message).

I am developing on and targeting a 64-bit system and version of Windows, so my understanding from the documentation is that I need to use `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32` to calculate the buffer size, ie.:

```
ReplySize >= sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32) + RequestSize + 8
```

However when testing this, the `IcmpSendEcho` always fails instantly with return value 0.
For `RequestSize < 4`, `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, which the documentation says indicates that "the *ReplySize* parameter specifies a value less than the size of an ICMP_ECHO_REPLY or ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32 structure".
For `RequestSize >= 4`, `GetLastError` returns an undocumented value that when parsed with [`GetIpErrorString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getiperrorstring) indicates "General failure".

I also see that the example code in the documentation excludes the 8 bytes in the reply buffer that is specified as required for an "ICMP error message" (and have seen [speculation that 8 is incorrect for 64-bit platforms](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cbd4c7e4-0ac0-491b-ac74-136d89c1e718/icmpsendecho-on-64bit-platform?forum=vcgeneral)) - I am unsure if this affects the issue.

If I instead use `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY` for the `ReplySize` calculation, `IcmpSendEcho` no longer fails for any payload size, however it still seems unclear which the function actually uses internally. Ie., is `ReplyBuffer` written as an array of `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY` or `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32`? Since once must access the buffer via casting the pointer type, using the wrong type could silently misalign and mangle all operations on it.

**So how should the reply buffer be set up correctly? Should `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY` or `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32` be used?**

This is the test code I have been working with:

```
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <IcmpAPI.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    // Create the ICMP context.
    HANDLE icmp_handle = IcmpCreateFile();
    if (icmp_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        throw;
    }

    // Parse the destination IP address.
    IN_ADDR dest_ip{};
    if (1 != InetPtonA(AF_INET, "<IP here>", &dest_ip)) {
        throw;
    }

    // Payload to send.
    constexpr WORD payload_size = 1;
    unsigned char payload[payload_size]{};

    // Reply buffer for exactly 1 echo reply, payload data, and 8 bytes for ICMP error message.
    constexpr DWORD reply_buf_size = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32) + payload_size + 8;
    unsigned char reply_buf[reply_buf_size]{};

    // Make the echo request.
    DWORD reply_count = IcmpSendEcho(icmp_handle, dest_ip.S_un.S_addr,
        payload, payload_size, NULL, reply_buf, reply_buf_size, 10000);

    // Return value of 0 indicates failure, try to get error info.
    if (reply_count == 0) {
        auto e = GetLastError();

        // Some documented error codes from IcmpSendEcho docs.
        switch (e) {
        case ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
            throw;
        case ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
            throw;
        case ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY:
            throw;
        case ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            throw;
        case IP_BUF_TOO_SMALL:
            throw;
        }

        // Try to get an error message for all other error codes.
        DWORD buf_size = 1000;
        WCHAR buf[1000];
        GetIpErrorString(e, buf, &buf_size);
        throw;
    }

    // Close ICMP context.
    IcmpCloseHandle(icmp_handle);
}
```

Comment: you should always use `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY`

Comment: Reported this a documentation bug, see: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the documentation to be wrong.

If you look at what's actually *in* an ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32, you will find some pointers declared with the `__ptr32` attribute, and there's some information about these guys [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793434/5743288).

**However**, when you actually dereference one of these, it turns out to be a bona-fide 64 bit pointer after all, which is not what it says in Hans' post.  I guess things have changed since he wrote that (tested by me on Visual Studio 2017 just now).

Anyway, go figure, but what is breaking your code is that `sizeof` for such a pointer returns *4*, even in a 64 bit build, and this means that the total reported size of an `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32` structure is not large enough (with such a small payload) to hold even a single ICMP reply and so `IcmpSendEcho` fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, as you have observed.

SO, all you have to do to get your code to work is to use `sizeof (ICMP_ECHO_REPLY)` when setting up your request and then cast `reply_buf` to `const ICMP_ECHO_REPLY *` in order to interpret the results.

Here is the entire code of my (working) test program, with some logging added (I stripped out some of your error handling for brevity):

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <IcmpAPI.h>

#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    // Create the ICMP context.
    HANDLE icmp_handle = IcmpCreateFile();
    if (icmp_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        throw;
    }

    // Parse the destination IP address.
    IN_ADDR dest_ip{};
    if (1 != InetPtonA(AF_INET, "89.238.162.170", &dest_ip)) {
        throw;
    }

    // Payload to send.
    constexpr WORD payload_size = 1;
    unsigned char payload[payload_size] { 42 };

    // Reply buffer for exactly 1 echo reply, payload data, and 8 bytes for ICMP error message.
    constexpr DWORD reply_buf_size = sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY) + payload_size + 8;
    unsigned char reply_buf[reply_buf_size]{};

    // Make the echo request.
    DWORD reply_count = IcmpSendEcho(icmp_handle, dest_ip.S_un.S_addr,
        payload, payload_size, NULL, reply_buf, reply_buf_size, 10000);

    // Return value of 0 indicates failure, try to get error info.
    if (reply_count == 0) {
        auto e = GetLastError();
        DWORD buf_size = 1000;
        WCHAR buf[1000];
        GetIpErrorString(e, buf, &buf_size);
        std::cout << "IcmpSendEcho returned error " << e << " (" << buf << ")" << std::endl;
        return 255;
    }

    const ICMP_ECHO_REPLY *r = (const ICMP_ECHO_REPLY *) reply_buf;
    struct in_addr addr;
    addr.s_addr = r->Address;
    char *s_ip = inet_ntoa (addr);
    std::cout << "Reply from: " << s_ip << ": bytes=" << r->DataSize << " time=" << r->RoundTripTime << "ms TTL=" << (int) r->Options.Ttl << std::endl;

    // Close ICMP context.
    IcmpCloseHandle(icmp_handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Run it at [rextester](http://rextester.com/FCX73017). (That's the IP address of my website, did you see what I did there? :)

**Note for future visitors:** This code does not check `r->Status` when `IcmpSendEcho` returns.  But it should do.  0 = success, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/ipexport/ns-ipexport-icmp_echo_reply32).

Comment: yes, documentation wrong. how minimum in win 8.1/win10 exactly `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY` used in x64 mode.

Comment: Thanks, @RbMm.  I will file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Out of curiosity, which part of the post about `__ptr32` is wrong? Isn't `__ptr32` actually 32-bits, and then it gets converted to 64-bit to dereference on 64-bit platforms? And it's just the smaller size of the `__ptr32` that causes `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32` to be too small?

Comment: @MCΔT Thank you, I trust you will [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  I'm not quite sure what the deal is with `__ptr32` but it's a weird one, that's for sure.  The compiler seems to be in two minds just how big it is.  I will pursue this.

Comment: @PaulSanders on my system, `__ptr32` seems to make it 32 bits, as opposed to the normal 64 bits for all other pointers. I suppose all the fuss about "coercing" it to 64-bit upon dereference is because the CPU cannot directly use a 32-bit pointer in 64-bit mode? Very weird, I'd much prefer they just give us one `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY` and let the compiler decide which pointer size is appropriate...

Comment: Yes, it's ridiculous.

Comment: i check - on win7 x64 also used exactly `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY` but not `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32` (may be this was only in 2003 x64 ?)

Comment: @RbMm I think the whole thing is a total mess, someone in the documentation department probably just screwed up.  `__ptr32` is something to do with Interop (see link in my post) but that's hardly relevant here.

Comment: `__ptr32` make pointer 32 bit size in 64 bit mode. `VOID * POINTER_32 Data;` is 4 byte always, when `VOID *  Data;` 8 byte in x64 mode. `C_ASSERT(sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY)==40);` for x64 when `C_ASSERT(sizeof(ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32)==28);`. but in test `ICMP_ECHO_REPLY` used exactly in x64 (how minimum begin from win 7)